# Show MySQL Results in a table without reloading page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a web application for database managing purposes. I've written front-end of the app on HTML+CSS3 and the server-side language is PHP, but I'm still confused about how to make MySQL calls and show it to the user without refreshing/reloading the page.

Trying to be specific, here are my doubts:

1. Can I execute a MySQL query without reloading a page?
2. How do I show a table with query's results?

Comment: You can use Ajax in this case.

Comment: @Fred-ii- is Ajax all what you have to advice for someone who is new to HTML CSS ?

Comment: Ajax is the key: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php

Comment: @Begueradj Sorry, I left out Google.

Comment: Pretty much everything you need to take a stab at this is found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841057/jquery-ajax-call-of-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use Ajax for this :**

Add this code to main page where you want to display table data

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function dashboard() {
var query_parameter = document.getElementById("name").value;
var dataString = 'parameter=' + query_parameter;

// AJAX code to execute query and get back to same page with table content without reloading the page.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "execute_query.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html) {
// alert(dataString);
document.getElementById("table_content").innerHTML=html;
}
});
return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="table_content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In **table_content** div the data come from **execute_query.php** page will load without refreshing the page.

**execute_query.php**

```
$user_name = $_POST['parameter'];

$query="SELECT * from info where name=$user_name";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$rs = mysql_fetch_array($result);

do
{
?>
<table>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $rs['city']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rs['phone_number']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
}while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```