# Show MySQL table and convert it into DataTables without refreshing the page

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I am trying to load a MySQL table and store it into an HTML table to then convert it into Datatables. However, I have some troubles pointing on the table I fetched with PHP.

I have already read these two pages ([page 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937238/show-mysql-results-in-a-table-without-reloading-page), [page 2](https://www.webscodex.com/2020/07/how-to-display-data-to-mysql-from-php.html)), but it does not show how to point on the table.

So here's my code :

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Connexion page. It is the first page og the web app -->
<html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />  
        <title>Temporis V Crafting List</title>
        
        <!-- DataTables CSS library -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>

        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

        <!-- DataTables JS library -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- JS script -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="memListTable" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>
    </body>

</html>
```

Nothing special here, I just store the table into `table#memListTable`.

**JavaScript**

```
function refresh_table() {
    // AJAX code to execute query and get back to same page with table content without reloading the page.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_table.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            // alert(dataString);
            console.log(html);
            $("#memListTable").html(html);
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    
    refresh_table();
    
    var table = $('#memListTable').DataTable({
        "columns": [
            {"data": "id"},
            {"data": "Item"},
            {"data": "Carte 1"},
            {"data": "Carte 2"},
            {"data": "Carte 3"},
            {"data": "Carte 4"},
            {"data": "Carte 5"}
        ]
    });
} );
```

Here I manually set the thead with DataTables columns.data options because I cannot seem to point on the full table.

**load_table.php**

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "temporis") or die("Echec de connexion à la base");

    $requette = "SELECT * FROM crafts";
    $resultat = mysqli_query($link, $requette);
    $rs = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat);
    
     
?>
    
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Carte 1</th>
                <th>Carte 2</th>
                <th>Carte 3</th>
                <th>Carte 4</th>
                <th>Carte 5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
                <?php do { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $rs['id']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rs['Item']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rs['Carte 1']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rs['Carte 2']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rs['Carte 3']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rs['Carte 4']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rs['Carte 5']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php }while($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat)); ?>
           
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Carte 1</th>
                <th>Carte 2</th>
                <th>Carte 3</th>
                <th>Carte 4</th>
                <th>Carte 5</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    

<?php
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

From teh code above I get the following web page :
[image]
I cannot filter the table, cannot order the columns, cannot interact at all with the DataTables. It works as `table#memeListTable` is empty when converting the html table into a DataTables.

I hope you guys will help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. The thing is to wait for the table to be filled with the content and then apply the DataTable function. I do it like this :

**JavaScript**

```
var table;

function refresh_table() {
    // AJAX code to execute query and get back to same page with table content without reloading the page.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_table.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $("#memListTable").html(html);
            table = $('#memListTable').DataTable();
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    refresh_table();
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can create dynamic table with php and mysql with datatables:

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Connexion page. It is the first page og the web app -->
<html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />  
        <title>Temporis V Crafting List</title>
        
        <!-- DataTables CSS library -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>

        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

        <!-- DataTables JS library -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- JS script -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="memListTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Carte 1</th>
                <th>Carte 2</th>
                <th>Carte 3</th>
                <th>Carte 4</th>
                <th>Carte 5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
       </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

**Table script:**

```
var memListTable = $('#memListTable').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: 'load_table.php',
        data: function() {
            //for sending extra params along with the URL above
            // if needed
            return {sample: "data"};
        },
        dataSrc: function(data) {
            return data || [];
        }
    },
    processing: true, // this will show loading whenever table reloads or any actions heppens with the table
    "columns": [
         {"data": "id"},
         {"data": "Item"},
         {"data": "Carte 1"},
         {"data": "Carte 2"},
         {"data": "Carte 3"},
         {"data": "Carte 4"},
         {"data": "Carte 5"}
     ]
});
```

**to refresh the table:**

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents default action 
    memListTable.ajax.reload(null, false); // this will reload the table everything user submits the form
});
```

**In load_table.php :**

```
$json = [];
var $sql = "SELECT * FROM crafts";
if ($result = $link->query($sql)) {
    foreach ($result AS $key => $row) {
        $json[] = $row;
    }
} else {
    $json['status'] = 'error';
    $json['message'] = 'Unexpected error';
    $json['error'] = $conn->error;
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

this is how easily you can create dynamic table in php and datables

Here is a link where I wrote an article about how to do it with daterange and others: https://sarifulislam.com/add-date-range-system-in-datatables/